# Simple window rendering problem with pyGLFW and Ubuntu on Wayland

Tags: python, ubuntu, glfw, wayland

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 and Python 3.8.10 on x64 CPU. Logged in to Ubuntu on Wayland. This simple test of pyGLFW 2.4.0:

```
import glfw

glfw.init()
window = glfw.create_window(640, 480, "Hello World", None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)

while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
  glfw.swap_buffers(window)
  glfw.poll_events()

glfw.terminate()
```

produces a defective window:

[image]

with this warning:

```
/home/paul/vis/.vis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/glfw/__init__.py:906: GLFWError: (65544) b'Wayland: Focusing a window requires user interaction'
  warnings.warn(message, GLFWError)
```

With normal login (X11?) the window produced by this script looks fine:

[image]

What is the problem? I prefer using Wayland, because I can't fix screen tearing on this PC with X11. Yes, I tried many helpful hints from interwebs.